# How to get all local variable names and values in C# using Python ScriptEngine?

Tags: c#, python, ironpython, scriptengine

I am using `Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine` and instantiate it via `IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateEngine()`. I then create a Scope and execute some python code.

I now would like to gather all locally assigned variable names and their values in C#. How can I extract all variable names and values that were declared and assigned in the Python script but from C# by querying the Python ScriptEngine and Scope?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via a dynamic object and reflection.
This is just winged code but if you send me or host the solution I can work it out for you.

```
dynamic someOject = IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateEngine();

foreach (var property in someOject.GetType().GetProperties())
     Console.WriteLine($"Property Name: {property.Name} - Property Value: {property.GetValue(someOject)}");
```

Not sure if this is what you're looking for or not... If not please let me know so I can further assist you.

Comment: thanks, though I just found possibly a simpler way via `scope.GetVariableNames()` and `scope.GetVariable(string variableName)`